# Benchmarks for CPython

Tags: python-3.x, benchmarking, performance-testing, cpython

I'm investigating a potential change in the CPython code base which I'm hoping may provide some performance benefits. However, though there are plenty of *functionality* tests in the build system, I can find nothing to do with *performance* testing.

I would think that this would be ideal in order to check both whether:

- any proposed performance improvements actually deliver what they intend; and
- whether any functionality changes cause serious performance issues.

Have I missed something in the repo, or is there a performance test somewhere else that I should be using?

I have no issue with building my own performance tests if need be (and delivering them into CPython if they're considered useful), I just wanted to ensure I wasn't duplicating effort unnecessarily.

Comment: In my (limited) experience, people put benchmarks into the bug tracker  but those never make it into any formalized VC.

Comment: Regex matching is CPU-intensive. Maybe some uber-regex matching on large text files could provide some interesting benchmarks.

Comment: @PabloPrieto: That would test the regex engine, but do very little to test changes outside the regex engine. They're just completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's Mercurial server has some [basic benchmarks available](https://hg.python.org/benchmarks) as a repo. The [README](https://hg.python.org/benchmarks/file/tip/performance/README) contains some basic info on them.