# Benchmarks for Python

Tags: python, performance

I want to create a list of Python benchmarks. Now I've found only standard benchmarks from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057850/benchmarks-for-cpython) question and some from [Computer Language Benchmarks Game](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/faster/python.html).

Are there any other benchmarks for Python? I'm looking for something like SPEC for C/C++ to compare different realizations of Python and Python performance on different machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Python Interpreters Benchmarks](https://pybenchmarks.org/)